# Why add `async` to a promise callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm looking at the following code [here](https://github.com/patrikx3/angular-compile/blob/master/src/CompileService.ts#L69):

```
cache[cacheKey] = new Promise(async(resolve) => { ...
```

Why is `async` added before the function? What's the difference between:

```
cache[cacheKey] = new Promise((resolve) => { ...
```

Comment: depends on the body of the `(resolve) => { ...`.  there is probably an `await` in there somewhere. :)

Comment: *Never* do that.

Comment: To answer the literal question: Because the author is clueless about promises. For the rest, I hope the duplicate target provides enough insight :-)

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, I'll take a look